# Dealloc not being called

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have a view controller, in which there's two ways to go back.

**First scenario goes like this:**

`RecordVC` -> tells `Delegate` to `dismissRecordVC:`-> `RecordVC` dismissed and deallocated

**Second scenario goes like this:**

`RecordVC` -> tells `Delegate` to `dismissAndShowVideosForRecordVC:`-> `RecordVC` dismissed and `VideosTVC` presented **BUT** `RecordVC` is NOT deallocated.

**First scenario is triggered like this:**

```
- (IBAction)back:(id)sender {
    if ([_chromaKeySessionManager isWriting]) {
        [_chromaKeySessionManager cancelWriting];
    }
    [_chromaKeySessionManager stopRunning];
    [delegate dismissRecordVC:self];
}
```

the delegate method `dismissRecordVC:` is this:

```
- (void)dismissRecordVC:(RecordVC *)vc {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

If this `back:` method is used, then RecordVC is deallocated just fine.

**Second scenario is triggered like this:**

```
- (IBAction)goToVideos {
    if ([_chromaKeySessionManager isWriting]) {
        [_chromaKeySessionManager cancelWriting];
    }
    [_chromaKeySessionManager stopRunning];
    [delegate dismissAndShowVideosForRecordVC:self];
}
```

and delegate's `dismissAndShowVideosForRecordVC:` method:

```
- (void)dismissAndShowVideosForRecordVC:(RecordVC *)vc {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        VideosTVC *vc = [[VideosTVC alloc] init];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [vc release];    
    }];
}
```

So, in this case, RecordVC never gets deallocated. The only difference here is this I am dismissing it with a completion block and pushing another controller.

To me, in both scenarios look the exact same (as far as retaining/releasing goes), except in first one it RecordVC get's deallocated and in latter scenario it never gets deallocated. Weird, and I know I shouldn't say this, but seems to be like an internal leak.

Is there something I am retaining that I am not aware of when using completion block for dismissing?
Thanks

Comment: dismissViewControllerAnimated is UIViewController's method. Check it out here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: In that case, somewhere in your code has a reference of VideoTVC being kept (retained?).

Comment: Do I really need to check? There's two scenarios, in one, it gets deallocated just fine, in other, as you can see right there, there's not much of a difference and no references being retained but it magically never gets deallocated. But i'll check once again to make sure

Comment: Also, VideoTVC has nothing to do with it. There's 3 view controller involved (2 in first scenario). RecordVC called Delegate to dismiss itself, Delegate dismisses RecordVC, and in 2nd scenario, Delegate, after dismissing RecordVC, pushed VideosTVC.

Comment: Updated my question to be more clear

Comment: You can do a quick test by changing that method to dismiss and push non-animated inline (without the completion block).  If that properly deallocates, then things get interesting.  If not, something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One difference is that the completion block references `self`.  That causes it to be at least retained until the block fires.  Admittedly, after that it ought to be released.

Try creating a local outside of the block to hold `[self navigationController]` and then use that local in the block so there's no reference to `self`.

I'll also point out that in `-dismissAndShowVideosForRecordVC:` you have a parameter and a local with the same name.  Shouldn't matter, but maybe there's a compiler bug.

Comment: I thought of this but stopped myself when I realized that self is not the thing that is being retained, it is the presented view controller.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Good call, didn't see the same variable name, so changed that (but still no difference). Created a local outside of block for navController, no difference.. :(

Comment: OK, so time to use the proper analysis tool: Instruments and Allocations instrument.  Run your app under that, provoke the case where something isn't deallocated when it should be, and then track all retains and releases on it.